# How to update value to null using Elasticsearch NEST APIs UpdateAsync method?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-api

I'm using `Elasticsearch NEST API` *(7.8.1)* and I'm having trouble with using `client.UpdateAsync<T>` method to update a value to null.

Is there any workaround to solve this issue?

**Example model:**

```
public class ProductSalesHistory
{
    public Id { get; set; }
    public Sku { get; set; }
    public Disposition { get; set; } //This should be null after update
}
```

**Example of the original document:**

```
{
    "id": 1, 
    "sku": "somesku", 
    "disposition": "C" 
}
```

**Example of updated document:**

```
{
    "id": 1, 
    "sku": "somesku", 
    "disposition": null 
}
```

**Example of NEST API call:**

```
var response = await Client.UpdateAsync<ProductSalesHistory>(id, u => u
    .Index(IndexName)
    .Doc(document)
    .DocAsUpsert(true)
    .Refresh(Refresh.False));
```

**As a result Elasticsearch NEST serializes updated document before sending it to API to such JSON:**

```
{
    "id": 1, 
    "sku": "somesku"
}
```

As you can see no "disposition" value was provided to Elasticsearch and as the result, nothing is changed in the document.

What I tried:

1. I tried to add `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]` attribute to `ProductSalesHistory.Disposition` property, but it didn't work.
2. Adding `() => new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include }` to `ConnectionSettings` as a parameter is not an option for me as I don't want to get side-effects on another queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem as follows, due to lack of other ideas:

```
var response = await Client.IndexAsync(document, i => i
    .Index(IndexName);
```

**IndexAsync** allows to update values to **null** and also supports update of existing documents and creation of new documents. As we do a lot of such operations I can say that performance of such updates is pretty much the same.